# What is the real function of an ID

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql

My teacher taught me that an ID´s function is to recognize data as unique but I don't know if it should be unique only in the table or in the general database.

Comment: You really mean *primary key*. It doesn't have to be called "ID" or even have "ID" in the name. That's just a convention. Given that, you could search on "sql purpose of primary key" and find lots of good information. It is unique per table and provides a unique identifier for each record in the table.

Comment: An identifier identifies a thing. What identifies what depends on the context. To be an identifier a value must get you to just one thing. Other than that, knowing that values in a collection are identifiers doesn't tell you about the collection. It's a generic term. A designer needs to say how identifications are happening in a context.  Usually no two values get you to the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely unique for the table. It is quite normal to have, for example, CustomerID starting at 1, ProductID starting at 1, etc.